# Read nested folder and file names as nested list

Tags: r

I'm trying to read all the folder and file names of a defined directory into a nested list that will be as long as the number of folders on the top level, then each list element has as many elements as in the sub-directory (if it is a folder) and so on until the level where there are only files and no more folders.

My use case is with my iTunes Music folder:

```
m <- "/Users/User/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music"  # set the path to the library folder
x <- list.files(m, recursive = FALSE)               # get all artists names (folder names on top level)
# read all Albums and title of each song per album
lst <- setNames(lapply(paste(m, x, sep = "/"), list.files, recursive = T), x)
```

The structure of each element in `lst` is now:

```
#$`The Kooks`                                       # artist name "The Kooks"
# [1] "Inside In Inside Out/01 Seaside.mp3"         # album name "Inside In Inside Out", title "01 Seaside.mp3"
# [2] "Inside In Inside Out/02 See The World.mp3"                 
#...                           
#[16] "Konk/01 See The Sun.mp3"                     # second album of The Kooks
#[17] "Konk/02 Always Where I Need To Be.mp3"
```

What I'm trying to do, is to make the entries of each artist nested lists, so in the example there would be the list element `$TheKooks` which has 2 (sub-)lists (1 for each album): `$Inside In Inside Out` and `$Konk` and each of the album lists has a vector of title names in it (without album names).

I couldn't find the right answers (yet) on SO and tried (unsuccessfully), among other things:

```
list.files(m, recursive = TRUE)
```

and

```
lapply(lst, function(l) {
  strsplit(l, "/")
})
```

How to do it properly?

P.S.:

- You can think of the desired output as a list-structure where each file/folder name only occurs as often as in the actual file/folders.
- As a best case, I'm hoping to find a solution that will be flexible enough to allow for different folder levels and will not require as many *explicit* lapply calls as the folder depths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function identifies files and folders in a directory. It then calls itself again for each identified folder, creating a list with any files and subfolders found.

```
fileFun <- function(theDir) {
    ## Look for files (directories included for now)
    allFiles <- list.files(theDir, no.. = TRUE)
    ## Look for directory names
    allDirs <- list.dirs(theDir, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
    ## If there are any directories,
    if(length(allDirs)) {
        ## then call this function again
        moreFiles <- lapply(file.path(theDir, allDirs), fileFun)
        ## Set names for the new list
        names(moreFiles) <- allDirs
        ## Determine files found, excluding directory names
        outFiles <- allFiles[!allFiles %in% allDirs]
        ## Combine appropriate results for current list
        if(length(outFiles)) {
            allFiles <- c(outFiles, moreFiles)
        } else {
            allFiles <- moreFiles
        }
    }
    return(allFiles)
}
## Try with your directory?
fileFun(m)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! That looks like a neat solution and based on initial test, seems to do what I wanted. Btw, I only meant that I wouldn't like to write x lapply calls manually according to the level of folders. Since this is recursive, it fulfills that criterion as I meant it. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

This solution should work, assuming that your directory structure is always `artist/album/songs`. If some directories are deeper (or less deep) you won't get what you want.

First, I get the list of directories (that is, the list of artists):

```
artists <- list.dirs(path=m,recursive=FALSE,full.names=FALSE)
```

Then I create the nested list:

```
lapply(artists,function(dir) {
  albums <- list.dirs(path=paste0(m,"/",dir),recursive=FALSE,full.names=FALSE)
  album.list <-
      lapply(albums,function(dir2) {
      list.files(path=paste0(m,"/",dir,"/",dir2))
  })
  names(album.list) <- albums
  album.list
})
```

And finally, I name the top level of the list:

```
names(music.list) <- artists
```

The album level works identically to the artist level: I get the directories (corresponding to the albums), then I list the files inside (corresponding to songs) and finally, I name the list elements by the album names.

**EDIT:**
As docendo discimus points out, the above solution is not general. The following recursive solution should do the job in a more elegant way:

```
rfl <- function(path) {
  folders <- list.dirs(path,recursive=FALSE,full.names=FALSE)
  if (length(folders)==0) list.files(path)
  else {
    sublist <- lapply(paste0(path,"/",folders),rfl)
    setNames(sublist,folders)
  }  
}
rfl(m)
```

It is still not fully general: As long as a folder contains subfolders, the algorithm descends into these folders *without* storing files that might also exist on the same depth into the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stibu! The output is indeed exactly what I wanted to get (+1). At the same time, I was hoping for a more general solution which would also work if there were different folder levels or many more and I wouldn't need to specify each level with a separate lapply call.

Comment: Yes, my solution is indeed neither general nor elegant. I'll be interested in the better solutions as well!

Comment: The edited version is very nice and already a pretty good improvement of the first, thanks again! Let's see if it can be fully generalized.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = list.files(m ,recursive = T)

music.df <- data.frame( artist = sapply(strsplit(files, '/'), '[[', 7), song =  paste( sapply(strsplit(files, '/'), '[[', 8), sapply(strsplit(files, '/'), '[[', 9) , sep = '/' ) )

out <- split( music.df[,2] , f = music.df$artist )
```

I put the artist and album/title into a data frame then used `split` to split the data frame into lists by artist

or you could make a data frame of the output of `strsplit` and then use `split` on the data frame.
 (ncol will vary depending on the depth of the folders)

```
files = list.files(m ,recursive = T) 
music.df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(files, '/')), ncol = 9, byrow = T) )
out <- split( music.df[,9] , f = music.df[7:8])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get an error in the second line. Also, it seems like a rather static solution.

Comment: I had to guess the position of artist and album based on the op. the actual subssets may be different